# Replace last line of config using bash?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have an `.env.branch` file with the following structure -

```
SOME_URL=https://somelink.com
SOME_OTHER_URL=https://someotherlink.com
SOME_FLAG=true
SOME_OTHER_OPTION=0
BRANCH_NAME=
```

My goal is to write a `bash` script that replaces the `BRANCH_NAME` config based on an environment variable called `BRANCH_NAME` (the number of lines in the config isn't fixed). This is how I am currently doing it -

```
echo "BRANCH_NAME=/"$BRANCH_NAME >> .env.branch
```

but all this does is append the line every time I run the bash script. So now I have -

```
SOME_URL=https://somelink.com
SOME_OTHER_URL=https://someotherlink.com
SOME_FLAG=true
SOME_OTHER_OPTION=0
BRANCH_NAME=
BRANCH_NAME=/somebranch
BRANCH_NAME=/somebranch
```

How can I achieve this using `sed` or some other bash feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should replace your last line with whatever new `BRANCH_NAME` you have, and save it. Just place the line in your bash script or enter it manually. Both work.

```
sed -i "s/BRANCH_NAME=.*/BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME}/" .env.branch
```

---

Result:

```sh
> mkdir sed
> nano .env.branch
> BRANCH_NAME=some_branch
> cat .env.branch 
SOME_URL=https://somelink.com
SOME_OTHER_URL=https://someotherlink.com
SOME_FLAG=true
SOME_OTHER_OPTION=0
BRANCH_NAME=
> sed -i "s/BRANCH_NAME=.*/BRANCH_NAME=${BRANCH_NAME}/" .env.branch
> cat .env.branch 
SOME_URL=https://somelink.com
SOME_OTHER_URL=https://someotherlink.com
SOME_FLAG=true
SOME_OTHER_OPTION=0
BRANCH_NAME=some_branch
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The command runs fine, when I `cat .env.branch` I still have `BRANCH_NAME=`

Comment: Is your `BRANCH_NAME` environment variable set? Because I personally tried it and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad it did :)

Answer (score 1):

With sed you could insert text before the last line, then remove the last line:

```
sed -e "\$iBRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME" -e '$d' inputfile
```

alternatively you could use `ex`:

```
ex -s +"/^BRANCH_NAME/norm A=$BRANCH_NAME" +wq inputfile
```

Comment: Why insert before the last line if you could just replace what is already available ?

Comment: It's an alternative solution without regex.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. It does worth either way and that's the whole point

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use `ed`, instead of `sed` and its non-standard `-i` option:

```
ed .branch.env <<EOF
/^BRANCH_NAME=/c
BRANCH_NAME=/somebranch
.
wq
EOF
```

This replaces the first line starting with `BRANCH_NAME=` with the desired line.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash specific [P.E.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

```
var=foobar

while read -r line; do
  echo "${line/BRANCH_NAME=/BRANCH_NAME=$var}"
done < file
```

The output

```
SOME_OTHER_URL=https://someotherlink.com
SOME_FLAG=true
SOME_OTHER_OPTION=0
BRANCH_NAME=foobar
```

This does not edit the file though. Just redirect to a new file.

Using ed to edit the file.

```
printf '%s\n' '/^\(BRANCH_NAME=\).*/s//\1foobar/' w | ed -s file
```

Since single quotes do not expand variables you can change to double quotes.

```
var=foobar
printf '%s\n' "/^\(BRANCH_NAME=\).*/s//\1$var/" w | ed -s file
```

Comment: I noticed you use the term `PE` in a similar context in another post - what does that mean?

Comment: Parameter Expansion.